# Is literary non-fiction on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Literary non-fiction is a form of non-fiction, in which the author uses the techniques of literature to describe a factually accurate account of a true occurrence. Is this on topic?

Comment: vtc'ing because the other one's a bit broader

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**, this is on-topic as long as the question is about the work itself and the question would be on-topic if it were asked about an equivalent fictional book. However, questions about the facts behind a work of literary non-fiction books, that are not intended to aid in the understanding of the work, are off topic and probably belong on a different Stack Exchange.